# Is there a way to add spacing or line-height in between lines on iTerm2?

Tags: terminal, themes, customization, iterm2

[Image of iTerm2 terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTP5D.png)

As you can see in the image, there's no separation between the lines. Is it possible to add line-height or space in between each new line?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

It's here (Profile => Text => Font)